# JSON load twitter API error

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I have used tweepy user timeline API to extract information for some users. Here is the [link](https://justpaste.it/1hdwz) to the file.

The content of the file is in string format. I tried to load the same using `JSON.loads(<string>)` but it is showing the error

> ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

I need to make the string to work as a dict/json so that I can iterate on the keys.

Comment: Can you post some part of string that you are trying to load using json.loads?

Comment: The "JSON" in the link is not a valid JSON, so you cannot use `json.loads`

Comment: Actually, i have dumped the twitter response to a file. Now it is string format. I need to convert it back to json.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the full code of how you implemented the API call, but also try converting it into a collection first. try 
`from collection import Counter
 Counter(data)`

Comment: `for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, user_id=rts).items():
 rtes_timeline.append(status._json)
`

Here, rts is a user list.

I then put the contents to a file.  
`fp.write(str(rtes_timeline) + "\n\n")`

Comment: try writing to the file using json dump instead of converting it to a string, e.g. `import json
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)`

Comment: I forgot to do it. Isn't there any other alternative?